# make one common column from several columns

Tags: r, dataframe

my data:

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 
90L, 100L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L), col2 = c(20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L), 
    col3 = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 1120L, 
    40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L), col4 = c(40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 
    90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L), group1 = c(1L, 
    1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    group2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L
))
```

I want to get one from several columns in which the columns go one after the other, first the first group, and then the second.

what I want to get:

```
structure(list(new_col1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 
80L, 90L, 100L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 
110L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 40L, 
50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
50L, 60L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 50L, 
60L, 70L, 80L, 90L), new_group1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), new_group2 = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 
NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(data)

output <-
  setnames(melt(dt, id.vars = c('group1', 'group2'))[, c(4, 1:2)],
           new = c("new_col1", "new_group1", "new_group2"))
```

**Output**

```
output

    new_col1 new_group1 new_group2
 1:       10          1         NA
 2:       20          1         NA
 3:       30         NA          1
 4:       40          1         NA
 5:       50         NA          1
 6:       60         NA          1
 7:       70          1         NA
 8:       80         NA          1
 9:       90          1         NA
10:      100         NA          1
11:       20          2          2
12:       30          2          2
13:       40          2          2
14:       50          2          2
15:       60          2          2
16:       20          1         NA
17:       30          1         NA
18:       40         NA          1
19:       50          1         NA
20:       60         NA          1
21:       70         NA          1
22:       80          1         NA
23:       90         NA          1
24:      100          1         NA
25:      110         NA          1
26:       30          2          2
27:       40          2          2
28:       50          2          2
29:       60          2          2
30:       70          2          2
31:       30          1         NA
32:       40          1         NA
33:       50         NA          1
34:       60          1         NA
35:       70         NA          1
36:       80         NA          1
37:       90          1         NA
38:      100         NA          1
39:      110          1         NA
40:     1120         NA          1
41:       40          2          2
42:       50          2          2
43:       60          2          2
44:       70          2          2
45:       80          2          2
46:       40          1         NA
47:       50          1         NA
48:       60         NA          1
49:       70          1         NA
50:       80         NA          1
51:       90         NA          1
52:      100          1         NA
53:      110         NA          1
54:      120          1         NA
55:      130         NA          1
56:       50          2          2
57:       60          2          2
58:       70          2          2
59:       80          2          2
60:       90          2          2
```

Comment: And if I have more than 4 columns?

Comment: @GOGAGOGA If you have additional columns, like `col5`, `col6`, then it will work as is. The `[, c(4, 1:2)]` is just changing the order after I convert it to long form, and I also drop the `variable.name` column.

Comment: do I understand correctly that it applies to any number of columns and there is no need to change anything?

Comment: @GOGAGOGA If you have additional `group` columns, then those would need to be added to `id.vars`. However, instead of having to type them out, you could do some subsetting on the names, like `names(dt)[startsWith(names(dt), "group")]`. Or you can also provide column indices, if you know the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("col"), names_to = NULL, values_to = "new_col")

#> # A tibble: 60 x 3
#>    group1 group2 new_col
#>     <int>  <int>   <int>
#>  1      1     NA      10
#>  2      1     NA      20
#>  3      1     NA      30
#>  4      1     NA      40
#>  5      1     NA      20
#>  6      1     NA      30
#>  7      1     NA      40
#>  8      1     NA      50
#>  9     NA      1      30
#> 10     NA      1      40
#> # ... with 50 more rows
```

Comment: Is it possible instead of starts_with("col") specify column numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just replace `starts_with("col")` with `c(1,2,3,4)` or even `1:4`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  gather(var, new_col, -group1, -group2) %>% 
  select(new_col, new_group1 = group1, new_group2 = group2)
```